# how can a webapplication may have site collection like host-headers?

Tags: site-collection

When I try to find the site collection on the dev system I could see the below and wondering how can a webapplication may have site collection like this?

```
Get-SPWebApplication http://spdev01 | Get-SPSite | select URL

Url
---
http://spdev01
http://spdev01/default
http://spdev01/sites/abc
http://spdev01/sites/xyz
http://devsite.test.com
http://tubesite.test.com
http://tubesite.test.com/mysite/abc
http://tubesite.test.com/mysite/xyz
```

I would like to make the site collection "http://tubesite.test.com" as my root "http:// spdev01" is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As John said, you could achieve it with host-named site collection. But, the URL to root site collection will be same as server name i.e.

```
New-SPSite 'http://spdev01' -Name 'Applications Portal' -Description 'Applications root collection' -OwnerAlias 'SomeDomain\SomeUser' -language 1033 -Template 'BLANKINTERNETCONTAINER#0'
```

That being said, you could then create your first host-name site collection:

```
New-SPSite 'http://tubesite.test.com' -HostHeaderWebApplication 'http://spdev01' -Name 'Team sites' -Description 'Team site root' -OwnerAlias 'SomeDomain\SomeUser' -language 1033 -Template 'STS#0’
```

Since you're working on development machine, add the host header to your hosts file. For Production or UAT use the DNS.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

These are called "host-named site collections".  There is a detailed article about them on TechNet: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc424952.aspx